# builiding a multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have got couple of arrays.

Array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => 501
    [1] => 502
    [2] => 503
    [3] => 505
)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 503
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 505
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Now my desired array structure should be

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 503
                [1] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 505
                [1] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 501
                [1] => 0
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 502
                [1] => 0
            )

    )
```

My code is

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $v)
{
    if( $array2[$k][0] == $v)
    {
        $finalArr[] = array($array2[$k][0],$array2[$k][1]);
    }
    else
    {
        $finalArr[] = array($v,0);
    }


}
```

Now it's giving me the right array structure which I want but the value is missing for the elements which are present in both array.

Comment: Because 501 and 502 is not in second array

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

```
if( $array2[$k][0] == $v)
```

$k is referring to the index of $array1, not $array2... so unless the elements in both arrays are perfectly in sync, your script will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have changed the code a little bit and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a_vals2 = array_map(
    function ($v) { return $v[1]; },
    $array2
);
$result = $array1;
foreach (array_diff($array1, $a_vals2) as $v) {
    $result[] = array($v, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if( $array2[$k][0] == $v) will never return true (for provided arrays) because you're checking the indexes of the arrays together. For example, 503 == 501 and 505 == 502 on the second index. Seems to me like your code will just make a copy of the first array (in this example).